# Expresión regular para verificar números, guiones y comas?

Tags: php, java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola intento crear una expresión regular que verifique que la cadena ingresada sólo contenga  números, guiones y comas esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora:

```
^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: Por favor trata de colocar para que lenguaje en especifico la desarrollas ya que según el lenguaje existen algunas diferencias en la sintaxis y procesamiento de expresiones regulares. Un saludo!

Comment: Pero tiene que contener los tres tipos de caracteres o restringir que la cadena sólo pueda contener esos caracteres, pero sin la necesidad de que los tres estén presentes en la cadena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente `RegEx`:

```
^[0-9,-]+$
```

Con lo cual indicas que solo aceptas numeros del `0-9` , `,` y `-`.

Answer (score 0):

`RegExp` con notación alternativa:

```
^[\d,-]+$
```

Donde `\d` equivale a `0-9`.